# LaTeX code won't compile, can't find error

Tags: math-mode, errors

quick question -- I was writing up a proof in LaTeX and my code isn't compiling :(. I narrowed down the offending region to the part with the % signs in front, but I can't seem to locate the error. Please help!

```
\begin{align*}
\frac{dr}{dt}&=r(1-r^2)\\
\int \frac{dr}{r(1-r)(1+r)}&=\int dt\\
\int_{r_0}^{r_1} \frac{dr}{r(1-r)(1+r)}&=\int_0^{2\pi} dt\\
\int_{r_0}^{r_1}\frac1r+\frac{\frac12}{1-r}-\frac{\frac12}{1+r}dr&=t\bigg|_0^{2\pi}\\
\ln|r|-\frac12\ln|1-r|-\frac12\ln|1+r|\bigg|_{r_0}^{r_1}&=2\pi\\
\ln\bigg|\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\bigg|\bigg|_{r_0}^{r_1}&=2\pi\\    \ln\bigg|\frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}\bigg|-\bigg|\frac{r_0}{\sqrt{1-r_0^2}}\bigg|&=2\pi\\
\ln\left(\frac{r_1\sqrt{1-r_0^2}}{r_0\sqrt{1-r_1^2}}\right)&=2\pi\\
\frac{r_1}{\sqrt{1-r_1^2}}&=\frac{r_0}{\sqrt{1-r_0^2}}e^{2\pi}\\
%\left(\frac{r_1}{\sqrt{1-r_1^2}}\right)^2&=(\frac{r_0}{\sqrt{1-r_0^2}}(e^{2\pi}))^2\\
%\frac{r_1^2}{1-r_1^2}&=\frac{r_0^2}{1-r_0^2}\left(e^{4\pi}\right)=A\\
%r_1^2 &= (1-r_1^2)A\\
%(1+A) r_1^2 &=A\\
%r_1&=\sqrt{\frac{A}{1+A}}\\
%r_1&=\sqrt{\frac{r_0^2 e^{4\pi}}{1-r_0^2+r_0^2e^{4\pi}}}\\
r_{n+1}&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{{r_n^{-2}e^{-4\pi}-e^{-4\pi}+1}}}\\
\mathcal{P}(r_n)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-4\pi}(r_n^{-2}-1)+1}}\\
\end{align*}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome! When I wrap your code into `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`, I do not get an error after removing the `%`. So the error is likely coming from somewhere else. (There are several examples of bad practice, though.)

Comment: As always on the site: full minimal example please. We have no idea which class your are doing and given the vast amount of templates there is on overleaf, we need to know exactly what we are dealing with here. Your code compiles fine for me, with or without those lines

Comment: even with everything uncommented this makes no errors, why do you think those lines are the problem, please provide an example code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the code was compiling on the next page and I had the zoom set only to the current page, sorry :). Glad it worked, and thank you everyone for helping me.